# Downloading a webpage to computer doesn't fully work

Tags: html, css

I am trying to download my webpage which I made on WIX. When I use CTRL+S to save the complete webpage and I load the site from my computer, not everything works. Is there some code missing when you save the webpage like this? 
The original site looks like this:

https://i.gyazo.com/c4465c93bfcfe19fb07876aed9791d93.mp4

The saved site looks like this:

https://i.gyazo.com/d42aa6bae9e31572e48e42ce8768e784.mp4

So the only thing that is different, is that the background isn't moving and the subscribe box at the bottom is missing at the saved page.

Sorry if this is not the place to ask this, but I thought it might has something to do with the code.

You can view the full html code at the original website (it's too much for the thread) https://jippie1912.wixsite.com/1912sites

Comment: If you need the full website that you created on services like wixi then you need to pay the service

Comment: Really? Isn't there a way to bypass that?

Comment: I really need an answer to this as fast as possible.. I promised someone that I would make the website for his company and now I don't know what to do..

Answer (score -2):

well,luckily i got the solution for the problem,but might take too long if your site has a lot of pages.You have to go to all your site pages and download them,so this way you can fix this without any advanced code.Tell me if it worked

Comment: did you used chrome?Best choice is Firefox.

Comment: WELL DID IT WORKED?

Comment: well then to resolve this wil realy be needed some code,i will notify you when i can resolve this